# Cloud hosting python code + MongoDB + cron

Tags: python, mongodb, cron, cloud

I'm looking for a free solution that allows for a python script to be run as a scheduled task. The script connects to a MongoDB that I would like to have on the same server. The DB will be smaller than 1GB.

Intuitively, what I need is a computer which I can access remotely, that runs scheduled tasks, and where I can install MongoDB Server, Python, and all the python libs the code needs.

I've tried to understand the solutions of aws, but get a bit confused with all the different solutions they offer.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Heroku Cloud](https://www.heroku.com/python) is nice platform to upload python apps. Also it provides an [add on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to schedule tasks. Although it provides mongo database as an add on, you may want to use [mongo lab](https://mlab.com/) , which provides 500mb of free storage.